# If an Electrical Field can jump over a point on its stright path of propagation?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, electromagnetism, particle-physics

Consider point B between points A and C on a stright line in vaccum(or any other environment). If the electrical fild $\vec E$ (or an EM wave) should necessarily pass through B to affect C and appear there on C?
I mean if on a path of a propagating field we should always have a continuous set of points which the mentioned field affect and pass through them? Why/Why not?

Answer (score 2):

> Consider point B between points A and C on a stright line in vaccum(or any other environment). If the electrical fild E⃗  (or an EM wave)

There is a big difference between an [Electric Field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_field) and an [electromagnetic wave.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_wave)

The electric field is a static description of the force felt by a point charge in space. It is a static picture, nothing is going anywhere when one has an electric field. There is no way of skipping anything.

The electromagnetic wave has two frameworks, the classical and the quantum mechanical. Classically there is continuity in the motion of the wave, which has a beginning and an end and is emitted by a source, and antenna, an incandescent lamp, etc.

Classically it cannot skip B.

> should necessarily pass through B to affect C and appear there on C? I mean if on a path of a propagating field we should always have a continuous set of points which the mentioned field affect and pass through them? Why/Why not?

Again, for the EM wave:
Quantum mechanically the EM wave is composed by an ensemble of photons. Each individual photon is constrained by the [Heisenberg Uncertainty principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg_uncertainty_principle) and depending on the accuracy of our measurement of the momentum of the indvidual photon there is a probability within the HUP it may skip B. But as the wave is composed by an ensemble of photons and the transition between classical and quantum mechanical formats is smooth, another photon will pass B and it will be impossible to determine a skip before reaching C.

Comment: Thanks; First: can't we consider a  wave as a dynamic view of a field?? I mean if they have the same natures and ?

Comment: No, the electromagnetic wave has momentum, it propagates. The electric field is static.The electric field does not have a magnetic component. Radiation happens with accelerated charges , i.e. changing electric fields that generate magnetic field etc.  you have to read up if you are interested in physics.

Comment: Thanks; First: can't we consider a  wave as a dynamic view of a field?? I mean if they have the same nature and make up? Second: I know they are different macroscopically some how, this is stationary but that is traveling and propagating but I have the same question about continuity of a Field line and a wave.  Third: I asked about the "reality" ,(or at least The most accurate one)  independent from different viewpoints and frameworks which exist for dealing with physics problems. Thank you again :)

Comment: Yes, the wave is the propagating form of the electric and magnetic fields, it changes in time. The electric field by itself is static and so is the magnetic field. Motion must be supplied to charges (and magnets) in order to generate electromagnetic radiation, which is independent of the fields. The fields take the provided energy by the motion and turn it into the electromagnetic wave. Reality means ability to measure in physics. We measure electric fields by the force felt by point charges. Electromagnetic we detect in many ways, including with our eyes. light is em wave.

Comment: yup. but considering magnetic field or not doesn't change the situation. plus , by "nature" I meant for example are they both established by the exchange of photons? By the way,you mean quantum mechanically we don't know exactly if it passes through B ? and it depends on if a photon of the wave passes B or not, and it has a probability function and we are not sure if it happens or not. Did I get it right??

Comment: you think so? but I don't think Reality means ability to measure in physics...I believe reality is something maybe quite different from what we measure. We all just try to interpret and justify our imprecise measurements using mathematics and calculations...  :)

Comment: Actually, I have thought about it so much. I think based on Gauss theorem it's macroscopically and of course classically impossible; But considering quantum physics, it may depend on quantum properties of a field/wave make up, and also continuity scale of space in comparison with smallest distance detectable by a field/wave (I mean who knows, there may exist some tiny gaps, so tiny that makes them incapable of including fields/waves. ;)  What's your idea?? ).

Comment: I have told you the current status of fields/radiation  classically and quantum mechanically. There is no experimental evidence that space is discrete, though there are people theorizing about it, like 't Hooft . Look at his answers http://physics.stackexchange.com/users/11205/g-t-hooft .